# AFNetworking NTLM Authentication not getting records

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, ntlm

I have a web service which when hit on web browser asks for username and password. I have to integrate same web service in my mobile app.

I searched a lot and got [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18385) which helps in implementing NTLM Authentication via AFNetworking.

Now under success block I am not getting response data. I am getting 0 records.
**Success: {"records":[]}**

Whereas hitting service on web browser I get all the records.

below is my code

```
NSString *str = @"complete web service url";

NSString *encode = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"userName" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:encode parameters:nil error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCredential:credential];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", [operation responseString]);
    
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Can anyone help me please that what is causing the problem. Thanks in advance.